# Poi + StreamingReader

Tags: apache-poi

I am using `StreamingReader` with Apache POI but unable create the `FormulaEvaluator` getting following exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
>       at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbook.getCreationHelper(StreamingWorkbook.java:432) ~[xlsx-streamer-1.0.2.jar:?]

Whether we able to create `FormulaEvaluator` with `POI`+`StreamingReader`?

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(4096).open(inputStream);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
```

Comment: Looks like the answer is "No". IIRC the streaming reader add-on is pure read-only